# Algorithm to remove words from a trie whose frequency < 5 and length > 15

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, trie

I have a huge trie dictionary that I built from data from web. Although it is just 5MB when I write the trie into a file its' size is so big when I load it on the memory (more than 100 MB). So I've to compress the trie.

I am facing difficulties in writing a recursive function (preferably runs in linear time like a DFS) to remove the words whose frequency is < 5 and length > 15. Any help is appreciated

Here is my trie structure.

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ch = '|'
        self.score = 0
        self.childs = [None]*26
        self.isWord = False


class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode('$')

    @staticmethod
    def print_trie(node, level):
        if node is None:
            return
        print(node.ch, " ", level, " ", node.isWord)
        for i in range(26):
            Trie.print_trie(node.childs[i], level+1)

    def insert(self, word):
        word = word.lower()
        if not is_valid(word):
            return
        childs = self.root.childs
        i = 0
        while i < len(word):
            idx = to_int(word[i])
            if childs[idx] is not None:
                t = childs[idx]
            else:
                t = TrieNode(word[i])
                childs[idx] = t
            childs = t.childs

            if i == len(word)-1:
                t.isWord = True
                t.score += 1
            i += 1

    def search_node(self, word):
        word = word.lower()
        if not is_valid(word):
            return False, 0
        if self.root is None or word is None or len(word) == 0:
            return False, 0

        children = self.root.childs
        for i in range(len(word)):
            idx = to_int(word[i])
            if children[idx] is not None:
                t = children[idx]
                children = t.childs
            else:
                return False, 0
        if t.isWord:
            return True, t.score
        else:
            return False, t.score
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method takes a node and its level (initially pass in root and 0) and returns True if the node should remain alive after pruning and False if the node should be removed from the trie (with its subtrie).

```
def prune(node, level):
  if node is None:
    return False
  canPruneNode = True
  for idx in xrange(len(node.children)):
    # If any of the children remains alive, don't prune current node.
    if prune(children[idx], level + 1):
      canPruneNode = False
    else:
      # Remove dead child.
      node.children[idx] = None
  if node.isWord and level > 15 and node.score < 5:
    node.isWord = False
  # Current node should be removed if and only if all of its children
  # were removed and it doesn't represent a word itself after pruning.
  return node.isWord or not canPruneNode
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if removing will solve the problem. The space consumed is not because of the words but because of the 26 children every node has.

Eg. I have a word *cat* with frequency 30 & there's another word *cater* whose frequency is 10. So, if you delete the node for *t* in *cat* then all the subsequent nodes will be deleted (that is *cater* will be reduced to *cat*)

So, removing a word from Trie means nothing but setting its score to 0.

Comment: What I want is if you remove cater, then the Trie should only contain cat. (removing 2 nodes corresponding to 'e' and 'r') But the thing here is I've to remove all such words in just 1 dfs